# How to expand a fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application, i used fragments.  I want to expand the fragment when i swipe the screen left to right.  I tried below code but not expanding.  How can i ?

```
    public class LeftFrag extends Fragment implements OnGestureListener {
        private GestureDetector gDetector;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.leftfrag, container, false);

            TextView tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1);

            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
            Date date = new Date();
            tv1.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
            gDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), this);

            view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    gDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //return false;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 50; //120;
            int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 100; //200;

            String str = "Velocity vx " + velocityX + " vy " + velocityY + " sx " + e1.getX() + " sy " + e1.getY() + " ex " + e2.getX() + " ey " + e2.getY();
            Log.d("onFling", str );

    //        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    //        tv.setText(str);


    //        Log.d("Velocity", "sx " + e1.getX() + " sy " + e1.getY() + " ex " + e2.getX() + " ey " + e2.getY() + " Velocity1 " + velocityX + " Velocity2 " + velocityY);

             if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE &&
                     Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                 //From Right to Left
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "From Right to Left " + str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 str = "From Right to Left " + str;
                 return true;
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE &&
                         Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                //From Left to Right
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "From Left to Right " + str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                str = "From Left to Right " + str;
                getActivity().getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT , LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT );
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.leftfrag);
                return true;
            }

            if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE &&
                        Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "From Bottom to Top " + str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                str = "From Bottom to Top " + str;
                //From Bottom to Top
                return true;
            }  else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE &&
                        Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                //From Top to Bottom
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "From Top to Bottom " + str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                str = "From Top to Bottom " + str;
                str = str + " 1233";
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
                float distanceY) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: "but not working well" is not a problem description.

Comment: OK... i changed it...

Comment: I cannot believe the edit you just made. I meant you should tell us what exactly the problem is and not just change the wording. How do you think that changing "but not working well" to "How can i ?" is going to improve your question? Tell us 1) What the problem is 2) What you tried so far to fix it 3) Why your attempts to fix it failed. You cannot just post code here and expect us to fix it for you.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I just confused to passing the correct reason.  Now i got own solution.  Please see my answer to the post.  Anyway thanks for denoting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway i got it... my updated code

```
    public class LeftFrag extends Fragment implements OnGestureListener {
        private GestureDetector gDetector;
        private int nWidth = 0, nHeight = 0;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.leftfrag, container, false);



            TextView tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1);

            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
            Date date = new Date();
            tv1.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
            gDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), this);

            view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    gDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //return false;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 50; //120;
            int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 100; //200;

            String str = "Velocity vx " + velocityX + " vy " + velocityY + " sx " + e1.getX() + " sy " + e1.getY() + " ex " + e2.getX() + " ey " + e2.getY();
            Log.d("onFling", str );

    //        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    //        tv.setText(str);


    //        Log.d("Velocity", "sx " + e1.getX() + " sy " + e1.getY() + " ex " + e2.getX() + " ey " + e2.getY() + " Velocity1 " + velocityX + " Velocity2 " + velocityY);

             if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE &&
                     Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                 //From Right to Left
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "From Right to Left " + str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 str = "From Right to Left " + str;

                 View view = getView();
                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(nWidth, nHeight);
                 view.setLayoutParams(p);
                 view.requestLayout();       
                 return true;
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE &&
                         Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                //From Left to Right
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "From Left to Right " + str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                str = "From Left to Right " + str;
                nWidth = getView().getWidth();
                nHeight = getView().getHeight();
                Log.e("Log", "Width = " + nWidth + " Height = " + nHeight );

                View view = getView();
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                view.setLayoutParams(p);
                view.requestLayout();       
                return true;
            }

            if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE &&
                        Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "From Bottom to Top " + str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                str = "From Bottom to Top " + str;
                //From Bottom to Top
                return true;
            }  else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE &&
                        Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                //From Top to Bottom
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "From Top to Bottom " + str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                str = "From Top to Bottom " + str;
                str = str + " 1233";
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
                float distanceY) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now fragment expanded and collapsed well

thanks